# Settings for sending email with PHP using GMail SMTP server for my domain

Tags: smtp, gmail

I run my business email through Google Mail, using my own domain (i.e. my email address is 'info@mydomain.com').  I've recently set up a support forum on my website which needs to send emails from the site admin via a PHP script.  However, none of the settings I've tried seem to work.  I thought these would work but they don't:

```
SMTP server: smtp.mydomain.com
SMTP username: info@mydomain.com
Password: test123
```

I've also tried setting up a different email account on my domain on the server and using the server IP and settings for this different account but I can't get this working either.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?  Do I need to use Google's own SMTP settings as opposed to those for my domain?

I don't know much about this so apologies if it's a dumb question - I've tried searching but can only find examples where people are actually using GMail as their email account rather than their own domain.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds a lot more suited to SuperUser instead of StackOverflow as you seem quite sure that this isn't the script itself.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I've tried those settings but no joy. This is all configured in the software I'm using (WHMCS) which is pretty well-established so I'm sure it's more a problem with my environment rather than their software.  I've tried to run the PHP script in your link above by itself and I get an error: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear').  Could it be that PHP Pear isn't installed on my server? I'm using a windows 7 server, PHP5. When I run phpinfo() it says: include_path .;./includes;./pear .;./includes;./pear - does this mean anything to you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with WHMCS, which they have apparently since resolved (although it was a show-stopper for me at the time so I wasn't able to see the resolution through).